# Is it possible to restore my deleted account

Tags: discussion

Long time ago, i had have an account here on askubuntu with high reputation. Then for some reasons i've asked to delete my account. Now i'm asking for the possibilty to restore that account or to restore my old reputation.

It it possible?! if yes how? and if no why?

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this. If the answer is no, just answer with no :/  My guess is, the answer is no, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an account is deleted, all data associated with that account is anonymised, the way that the account is deleted will depend on a variety of factors including how much network reputation you had when the account was deleted and how frequently you voted.

When your account is deleted, the following will happen

- All posts (questions, answers and comments) you've made will be anonymised and will simply display `user<youruserid>` as the poster name
- All review queue history will be removed from the database
- If you were a frequent voter, these votes will be assigned to the community user, if not, they will all be reverted
- All of your edit activity will be anonymised and associated with the community user

While it is possible, in rare circumstances, to recover a deleted account, this is an extremely time consuming manual process that must be performed by Stack Exchange, and will only result in a partial undeletion. Undeleting an account is purely at Stack Exchange's discretion and is not a service they generally offer due to the time consuming nature. Account deletions are considered permanent with exceptions for edge cases.

In the event Stack Exchange were willing to undelete your account, you would only regain your post history (questions, answers, comments) and upvotes and downvotes associated with those posts. You would not get the following back, as it cannot be "undeleted":

- Any bounties you've earned
- Any reputation you've earned from suggested edits
- Edit history
- Review queue history
- Flag history

I will repeat, so you don't get your hopes up too much, but an account undeletion is **purely at the discretion of Stack Exchange, and is a time consuming manual process**. In most instances, it's quicker to just create a new account and resume your active participation in the site(s) you wish to participate in.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer is no, there is no method to recover your account.

According to the stack exchange team there is no "recovery" method available and everything would need to be rebuilt by hand, and that is not going to happen...

The fastest way of getting your reputation back would be to create a new account and start participating again on the website.

Comment: This is really a fallacy in my opinion. What happens if you gained 10k rep for example? And that's going to take you at least half year fully involved on every aspect of the site. This is a weak point that should be enforced.

Comment: @slowbanned the deletion is manual and hard. All your data is removed from the databases carefully. When you ask for this is a point of no return. Your user do *puff*. If you don't know if you wish to come back just don't visit stack exchange instead of removing your account.

Comment: @slowbanned it's actually possible to earn 10k reputation in 50 days, well, it's actually possible to earn 10k reputation in less than 50 days, but that would involve answer accepts and bounties to push you over the 200 rep/day limit.

Comment: @slowbanned Its just an account and its just reputation, people think of reputation as something so much important than their contributions and that is just sad. What do you think when someone asks to delete a Google account and then sometime later regrets that? So you think you can email google and ask them to recover an email from an account that you deleted previously? There is a reason why we do not take deleting accounts as a light measure... Maybe that is why we ask the users to create a meta post asking for such, it is in most cases final and not to be taken lightly!